# OpenCV installation problems for Python

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, opencv

I am trying to install OpenCV on my Ubuntu system. I followed the steps of this [page](http://www.samontab.com/web/2014/06/installing-opencv-2-4-9-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/). I am able to run the demos for C/C++ etc. But when I try to run the python demos, I get an `ImportError: No module named cv2`

Here is more info :

`python --version
Python 2.7.8 :: Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)`

`python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'
['', '/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydy-0.2.1-py2.7.egg', '/home/radar', '/home/radar/opencv-2.4.9/modules/python/src2', '/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python27.zip', '/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7', '/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL', '/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.2.3-py2.7.egg', '/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/runipy-0.1.1-py2.7.egg', '/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-5.8-py2.7.egg']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running Anaconda Python distribution, but you need to use native python to access openCV library. Run Python with specified path and it should work:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

Also note, that to use openCV with virtual environmet, you need to manually copy openCV running objects (`cv.py`, `cv2.so`) to the environment you are going to use from the dist-packages of your native python, default path is `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`.

Comment: Nope, I am not able to find the openCV running objects (`cv.py, cv2.so`) in the dir `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`. I ran `sudo find . -print | grep -i 'cv'`

Comment: Have you run `cmake` command for openCV with the flag `BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON `? Also have you installed all prerequisits for it, as show in the tutorial (big bunch of `apt-get install`)?

Comment: I think I did. Is it fine if I run the `cmake` and all the following commands again ?

Comment: Yes, it will replace existing installation with the new one. So the `import cv2` is failing from the general python shell?

Comment: I am sorry, how do I access the general shell ? Everytime I issue `python`, I get Anacoda version :

`radar@radar-Inspiron-5420:~$ python

Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 28 2015, 17:02:03) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> `

Comment: Try run `/usr/bin/python` - it will start native python shell, if it installed. Using anaconda can cause a problem with installing opencv. Also, please note, if `import cv2` code works in any of these shells.

Comment: Yes ! I am able to import both `cv` and `cv2` in the native python version. Thank you for your help. You may edit the answer and I will mark it as correct.